# Tortoise SVN: Check-In and Check-Out

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

... or get latest and commit files, if you're a GitHub person like I am.

[I have read the documentation from TortoiseSVN about checking in files](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html).  They recommend the standard practice of getting the latest files before checking-in a file.  I agree.  Here's what they write:

You can either use `TortoiseSVN → Update` directly. Or you can use `TortoiseSVN → Check for Modifications`.

Sounds great, except this doesn't exist.  When I right-click on my folder I have two TortoiseSVN related options: `SVN Checkout ...` and `TortoiseSVN`.  Under the latter item, I see more sub-options, such as `Repo-browser`, `Export`, `Create repository here`, `Import`, `Settings`, `Help`, `About`.

Even when I go to the `Repo-browser` and right click, I see nothing with `Update` or `Check for modifications`.  These are the instructions, but I either have a much different version, or something else is wrong.

So, step-by-step, how do I check in an update.  Here are the steps I did to set up the original folder, so you can see exactly where I am in the process so you know what I need to do next.

1. Create a folder for the repository.
2. Right click and select `TortoiseSVN` => `Create repo here`
3. I receive a pop-up box that says `Repository Created` and I clicked `Start Repobrowswer`.
4. Once I am in the `Repobrowser`, I right-click and select `Checkout`, fill in the URL of the repo and the checkout directory, then click `OK`.  It loads all the items from the repository.

Good, so I have all the items.  Now, I need to check-in a folder with 6 files.  How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think is that you need to do following steps after checking out files from the repository.

1- Right click on your folder, choose tortoise svn, select add, a popup will appear, displaying all files not yet monitored by svn. choose whatever files you want and click ok.

2- If your files are not showing in the first popup, go to the files exact locations, right-click on the files and do the same as the previous step.

3- Now when you right-click on your folder you should have a "Svn Commit" item, select it, and commit window will appear. Select files and press commit

Good Luck

Comment: There is no `Add` sub-option when I right click on my folder and choose `TortoiseSVN`.

Comment: Let's try another approach, Create a folder, Right-Click, Select SVN Checkout, Enter your repository URL, then add your files. Now check if you have `Add` sub-option

Comment: If I right-click, select `SVN Checkout`, it brings up a dialog box asking me for the URL and checkout directory (with a recursive option, plus many other options).  If I do that, I get a warning that says `Target Folder Is Not Empty` more than likely because the local folder has the checked-out files.  But this folder, even if it has been checked-out, does not have an `Add` sub-option under the `TortoiseSVN` option.

Comment: Are you used to using git version control system?
I think you are trying to use SVN like git.
Try `SVN-Checkout` on an empty folder and do the rest of steps in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, but that's irrelevant.  There is no `Add` option.  Step-by-step show me how to get there; if it's there, it should appear at some point.  I don't see any `Add` sub-option.

Comment: Ok, let me explain myself, 
You know in git at first you create a local repository and then push it to a remote one. Although it's possible to create a remote repository first.
But in `SVN` you first check out a remote repository and then do your changes and commit back to the remote.

Now, you are saying that if you try `SVN-Checkout` on an empty folder, you still don't have `Add` option?

Comment: Also, check with your pre-commit/post-commit hooks, may people add this for formatted commit message with ticket number!